# Night Light on Raspberry Pi

Tags: nightlight, raspberry-pi

Is Night Light expected to work on Raspberry Pi with recent elementary OS 6.0 (Odin) builds? Mine has never worked. Just wondering if this is expected to be fixed by the final release or if there’s a hardware limitation on RPi that makes it non-functional. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hardware limitation according to [issue #1274](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1274) in the Rasberry Pi firmware.
If support is added, I wouldn't be surprised if it starts working in elementaryOS 6 or previous versions as the updated firmware becomes available.

There is also [an issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/issues/580) in the GNOME Settings daemon - which elementary OS uses for this feature - to expose whether or not the hardware supports Night Light.